# rails 5 db:reset not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to reset the database of my rails 5 project, but the `rails db:reset` command is not working.

errormessage:

```
Permission denied @ unlink_internal - C:/sites5/dawnrebirth/db/development.sqlite3
Couldn't drop database 'db/development.sqlite3'
rails aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - C:/sites5/dawnrebirth/db/development.sqlite3
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:drop:_unsafe
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Running commands `db:drop`, `db:create`, `db:migrate` one after another fix the issue for me. (And run `db:seed` if want to populate some test data.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Usually when `rake db:reset` don't run or work for me, I just delete the development.sqlite3 and schema.rb files and re run the `rake db:migrate` command to regenerate both files. But take note to Never try this in a production environment please.

Answer (score 6):

try `rails db:drop:_unsafe` see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31589

Answer (score 1):

Looks like rails tried to delete the file but did not succeed.
Check the following:

- is your app running and connected to the database file? — Terminate the app before executing `rake db:reset`.
- is some other process (for example a database viewer) connected to the database file? — Same as above, terminate it before reset.
- in the worst case (you cannot determine what is blocking the file), a `rake db:reset` immediately after reboot has a high probability to run successfully.

Answer (score 1):

When you do **rake db:reset**, it's running db:drop and db:setup in sequence.

1.Maybe you need to stop your Rails server and console.

2.A reboot may solve the problem too.

Answer (score 1):

*I was told to add my input for rails 5 as an answer, so by request ...*

First, stop the rails server.

Second, run these 3 commands ...

```
rails db:drop
rails db:schema:load
rails db:reset
```

I hate digging through files, so this is easier & faster for me than going to delete some file.  Caveat:  Whether you are using my fix or not - always backup your schema somewhere every day (like with a repo system...github/bitbucket).

I believe 'rake' can be used in place of rails for versions before rails 5, but haven't tested back to rails 3 or 2.

As @govind-shaw said ... either way, you have to stop the rails server & start it up again.