# With Rails, db:drop gives permission denied regarding development.sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

I am new to rails.

I am getting an error rather like the one mentioned [rails 5 db:reset not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39182630/rails-5-dbreset-not-working)   but **this is not a duplicate of that question, since the accepted on answer there doesn't work for me.**

I understand that db:reset involves a db:drop, I found I couldn't do a db:reset, I then tried a db:drop and found I couldn't do that either, which is even more fundamental, and gave the same error.

The error I get is when I do rails db:drop.  I get `Permission denied @ unlink_internal - C:/rubytest/blah2/db/development.sqlite3`

As you see below

```
C:\rubytest>rails --version
Rails 5.1.4

C:\rubytest>

C:\rubytest>rails new blah2
...

C:\rubytest\blah2>bundle update
...


C:\rubytest\blah2>rails db:drop
Permission denied @ unlink_internal - C:/rubytest/blah2/db/development.sqlite3
Couldn't drop database 'db/development.sqlite3'
rails aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - C:/rubytest/blah2/db/development.sqlite3
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:drop:_unsafe
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

C:\rubytest\blah2>
```

The accepted answer in the link I mentioned at the top of this question,  suggests (with a note not to do this in a production environment) "just delete the development.sqlite3 and schema.rb files and re run the rake db:migrate"

I didn't need to stop the rails server 'cos I hadn't started it anyway. I did that deletion, and rails db:migrate, then tried db:drop and still got the error.

```
C:\rubytest\blah2>dir C:\rubytest\blah2\db
...
23/12/2017  10:07 PM                 0 development.sqlite3
23/12/2017  10:06 PM               370 seeds.rb
..
C:\rubytest\blah2>


C:\rubytest\blah2>del C:\rubytest\blah2\db\development.sqlite3

C:\rubytest\blah2>dir C:\rubytest\blah2\db
23/12/2017  10:06 PM               370 seeds.rb

C:\rubytest\blah2>


C:\rubytest\blah2>rails db:migrate

C:\rubytest\blah2>dir C:\rubytest\blah2\db
23/12/2017  10:13 PM             5,120 development.sqlite3
23/12/2017  10:13 PM               786 schema.rb
23/12/2017  10:06 PM               370 seeds.rb
C:\rubytest\blah2>
```

Yet I still get the error

```
C:\rubytest\blah2>rails db:drop
Permission denied @ unlink_internal - C:/rubytest/blah2/db/development.sqlite3
Couldn't drop database 'db/development.sqlite3'
rails aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - C:/rubytest/blah2/db/development.sqlite3
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:drop:_unsafe
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

C:\rubytest\blah2>
```

I also tried `rails db:reset rails_env=development` (I understand the default is development anyway..) and I tried `rails db:reset rails_env=test` as mentioned here [Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ unlink_internal when running rake test:models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27138533/errnoeacces-permission-denied-unlink-internal-when-running-rake-testmodels) but    it made no difference

This looks like an unresolved bug  https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31589 (open but no response) and https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27015 (closed)

**Added**

I have included two examples here of logs from process monitor, that might hint to the issue. I did a filter where path contains ruby.

First log, is smaller.

I  started capture events, in process monitor , just before rails db:drop, and I stopped it just after.

```
C:\crp\aaa1>path
PATH=C:\Ruby24-x64\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs


c:\crp>rails new aaa1
...

C:\crp\aaa1>rails db:drop
Permission denied @ unlink_internal - C:/crp/aaa1/db/development.sqlite3
Couldn't drop database 'db/development.sqlite3'
rails aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - C:/crp/aaa1/db/development.sqlite3
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:drop:_unsafe
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

http://ge.tt/5DYspso2  Logfile1.csv  (size- 15KB)

```
Time of Day Process Name    PID Operation   Path            Result      Detail

56:43.1     cmd.exe     9476    RegOpenKey  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\ruby.exe NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Query Value, Enumerate Sub Keys
56:43.1 cmd.exe 9476    RegOpenKey  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Custom\ruby.exe    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Query Value
56:43.1 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Windows\Prefetch\RUBY.EXE-A86B99A9.pf    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: None, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.1 ruby.exe    1516    RegQueryValue   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Compatibility32\ruby  NAME NOT FOUND  Length: 172
56:43.3 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.3 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.3 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.3 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.3 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.4 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.4 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.4 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.4 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.4 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.5 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.5 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.5 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.5 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.5 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.5 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.5 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.6 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.6 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.6 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.6 ruby.exe    1516    CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.8 ruby.exe    1516    RegOpenKey  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\ruby.exe NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Query Value, Enumerate Sub Keys
56:43.9 ruby.exe    1516    RegOpenKey  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Custom\ruby.exe    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Query Value
56:43.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\Windows\Prefetch\RUBY.EXE-A86B99A9.pf    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: None, AllocationSize: n/a
56:43.9 ruby.exe    12108   RegQueryValue   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Compatibility32\ruby  NAME NOT FOUND  Length: 172
56:44.0 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:44.1 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:44.3 ruby.exe    12108   RegOpenKey  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ShellCompatibility\Applications\ruby.exe NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Query Value, Enumerate Sub Keys
56:44.6 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby\2.4.0\    PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Directory, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:44.6 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby\2.4.0\    PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Directory, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:44.6 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby\2.4.0\    PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Directory, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:44.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\Users\harvey\.gem\ruby   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\lib\bindex\cruby.rb PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\vendor\bindex\cruby.rb  PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\app\assets\bindex\cruby.rb  PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\app\channels\bindex\cruby.rb    PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\app\controllers\bindex\cruby.rb PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\app\controllers\concerns\bindex\cruby.rb    PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\app\helpers\bindex\cruby.rb PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\app\jobs\bindex\cruby.rb    PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\app\mailers\bindex\cruby.rb PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\app\models\bindex\cruby.rb  PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\app\models\concerns\bindex\cruby.rb PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\lib\bindex\cruby.so PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\vendor\bindex\cruby.so  PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\app\assets\bindex\cruby.so  PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\app\channels\bindex\cruby.so    PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\app\controllers\bindex\cruby.so PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\app\controllers\concerns\bindex\cruby.so    PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\app\helpers\bindex\cruby.so PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\app\jobs\bindex\cruby.so    PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\app\mailers\bindex\cruby.so PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\app\models\bindex\cruby.so  PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
56:59.9 ruby.exe    12108   CreateFile  C:\crp\aaa1\app\models\concerns\bindex\cruby.so PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
```

The main thing I notice in the log above is a lot of "PATH NOT FOUND". I don't know if that is normal or not.

I tried again from a different path, this time my environment path longer. I still got the same error on the command line, though the log was longer, and I  noticed an error about a sharing violation, which might not be relevant since in the log included earlier in this post, I got no such sharing violation error in the process  monitor log, but still got that permissions denied error at the command line.

> C:\rubytest\proj\testa

```
C:\rubytest\proj\testa>rails db:drop
Permission denied @ unlink_internal - C:/rubytest/proj/testa/db/development.sqlite3
Couldn't drop database 'db/development.sqlite3'
rails aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - C:/rubytest/proj/testa/db/development.sqlite3
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:drop:_unsafe
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The log is huge - 2MB - i'll link to it here.

logfile2.csv http://ge.tt/9axXqso2

And i'll include the very end of it here

```
5:00:39.1378504 PM  ruby.exe    896 UnlockFileSingle    C:\rubytest\proj\testa\db\development.sqlite3   SUCCESS Offset: 1,073,741,826, Length: 510
5:00:39.1382490 PM  ruby.exe    896 CreateFile  C:\rubytest\proj\testa\lib\pathname.rb  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
5:00:39.1383816 PM  ruby.exe    896 CreateFile  C:\rubytest\proj\testa\vendor\pathname.rb   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
5:00:39.1385064 PM  ruby.exe    896 CreateFile  C:\rubytest\proj\testa\app\assets\pathname.rb   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
5:00:39.1386275 PM  ruby.exe    896 CreateFile  C:\rubytest\proj\testa\app\channels\pathname.rb NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
5:00:39.1387511 PM  ruby.exe    896 CreateFile  C:\rubytest\proj\testa\app\controllers\pathname.rb  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
5:00:39.1388726 PM  ruby.exe    896 CreateFile  C:\rubytest\proj\testa\app\controllers\concerns\pathname.rb NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
5:00:39.1389937 PM  ruby.exe    896 CreateFile  C:\rubytest\proj\testa\app\helpers\pathname.rb  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
5:00:39.1391185 PM  ruby.exe    896 CreateFile  C:\rubytest\proj\testa\app\jobs\pathname.rb NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
5:00:39.1392371 PM  ruby.exe    896 CreateFile  C:\rubytest\proj\testa\app\mailers\pathname.rb  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
5:00:39.1393550 PM  ruby.exe    896 CreateFile  C:\rubytest\proj\testa\app\models\pathname.rb   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
5:00:39.1394740 PM  ruby.exe    896 CreateFile  C:\rubytest\proj\testa\app\models\concerns\pathname.rb  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
5:00:39.1506563 PM  ruby.exe    896 CreateFile  C:\rubytest\proj\testa\db\development.sqlite3   SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
5:00:39.1506850 PM  ruby.exe    896 QueryBasicInformationFile   C:\rubytest\proj\testa\db\development.sqlite3   SUCCESS CreationTime: 7/03/2018 5:00:38 PM, LastAccessTime: 7/03/2018 5:00:38 PM, LastWriteTime: 7/03/2018 5:00:38 PM, ChangeTime: 7/03/2018 5:00:38 PM, FileAttributes: A
5:00:39.1507039 PM  ruby.exe    896 CloseFile   C:\rubytest\proj\testa\db\development.sqlite3   SUCCESS 
5:00:39.1507888 PM  ruby.exe    896 CreateFile  C:\rubytest\proj\testa\db\development.sqlite3   SHARING VIOLATION   Desired Access: Read Attributes, Delete, Disposition: Open, Options: Non-Directory File, Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
5:00:39.1510446 PM  ruby.exe    896 CreateFile  C:\rubytest\proj\testa\db\development.sqlite3   SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
5:00:39.1510721 PM  ruby.exe    896 QueryBasicInformationFile   C:\rubytest\proj\testa\db\development.sqlite3   SUCCESS CreationTime: 7/03/2018 5:00:38 PM, LastAccessTime: 7/03/2018 5:00:38 PM, LastWriteTime: 7/03/2018 5:00:38 PM, ChangeTime: 7/03/2018 5:00:38 PM, FileAttributes: A
5:00:39.1510939 PM  ruby.exe    896 CloseFile   C:\rubytest\proj\testa\db\development.sqlite3   SUCCESS 
5:00:39.1511788 PM  ruby.exe    896 CreateFile  C:\rubytest\proj\testa\db\development.sqlite3   SUCCESS Desired Access: Write Attributes, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
5:00:39.1512195 PM  ruby.exe    896 SetBasicInformationFile C:\rubytest\proj\testa\db\development.sqlite3   SUCCESS CreationTime: 1/01/1601 12:00:00 AM, LastAccessTime: 1/01/1601 12:00:00 AM, LastWriteTime: 1/01/1601 12:00:00 AM, ChangeTime: 1/01/1601 12:00:00 AM, FileAttributes: AN
5:00:39.1512766 PM  ruby.exe    896 CloseFile   C:\rubytest\proj\testa\db\development.sqlite3   SUCCESS 
5:00:39.1514227 PM  ruby.exe    896 CreateFile  C:\rubytest\proj\testa\db\development.sqlite3   SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
5:00:39.1514490 PM  ruby.exe    896 QueryBasicInformationFile   C:\rubytest\proj\testa\db\development.sqlite3   SUCCESS CreationTime: 7/03/2018 5:00:38 PM, LastAccessTime: 7/03/2018 5:00:38 PM, LastWriteTime: 7/03/2018 5:00:38 PM, ChangeTime: 7/03/2018 5:00:39 PM, FileAttributes: A
5:00:39.1514674 PM  ruby.exe    896 CloseFile   C:\rubytest\proj\testa\db\development.sqlite3   SUCCESS 
5:00:39.1515487 PM  ruby.exe    896 CreateFile  C:\rubytest\proj\testa\db\development.sqlite3   SHARING VIOLATION   Desired Access: Read Attributes, Delete, Disposition: Open, Options: Non-Directory File, Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
5:00:39.1632663 PM  ruby.exe    896 UnlockFileSingle    C:\rubytest\proj\testa\log\development.log  RANGE NOT LOCKED    Offset: 0, Length: 4,294,967,295
5:00:39.1632971 PM  ruby.exe    896 CloseFile   C:\rubytest\proj\testa\log\development.log  SUCCESS 
5:00:39.1633911 PM  ruby.exe    896 CloseFile   C:\rubytest\proj\testa\db\development.sqlite3   SUCCESS 
5:00:39.1648632 PM  SearchIndexer.exe   4652    CreateFile  C:\rubytest\proj\testa\db   SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Open By ID, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
5:00:39.1648915 PM  SearchIndexer.exe   4652    QueryNameInformationFile    C:\rubytest\proj\testa\db   SUCCESS Name: \rubytest\proj\testa\db
5:00:39.1649125 PM  SearchIndexer.exe   4652    CloseFile   C:\rubytest\proj\testa\db   SUCCESS 
5:00:39.1649995 PM  SearchIndexer.exe   4652    CreateFile  C:\rubytest\proj\testa  SUCCESS Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
5:00:39.1650336 PM  SearchIndexer.exe   4652    QueryInformationVolume  C:\rubytest\proj\testa  SUCCESS VolumeCreationTime: 31/08/2013 3:20:40 AM, VolumeSerialNumber: B411-D580, SupportsObjects: True, VolumeLabel: 
5:00:39.1650451 PM  SearchIndexer.exe   4652    QueryAllInformationFile C:\rubytest\proj\testa  BUFFER OVERFLOW CreationTime: 18/02/2018 9:48:00 PM, LastAccessTime: 18/02/2018 9:48:11 PM, LastWriteTime: 18/02/2018 9:48:11 PM, ChangeTime: 18/02/2018 9:48:11 PM, FileAttributes: D, AllocationSize: 4,096, EndOfFile: 4,096, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: True, IndexNumber: 0x280000000cdc2c, EaSize: 0, Access: Generic Read, Position: 0, Mode: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, AlignmentRequirement: Word
5:00:39.1650574 PM  SearchIndexer.exe   4652    CloseFile   C:\rubytest\proj\testa  SUCCESS 
5:00:39.1652249 PM  SearchIndexer.exe   4652    CreateFile  C:\rubytest\proj    SUCCESS Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
5:00:39.1652520 PM  SearchIndexer.exe   4652    QueryInformationVolume  C:\rubytest\proj    SUCCESS VolumeCreationTime: 31/08/2013 3:20:40 AM, VolumeSerialNumber: B411-D580, SupportsObjects: True, VolumeLabel: 
5:00:39.1652622 PM  SearchIndexer.exe   4652    QueryAllInformationFile C:\rubytest\proj    BUFFER OVERFLOW CreationTime: 16/02/2018 3:48:12 PM, LastAccessTime: 7/03/2018 4:48:01 PM, LastWriteTime: 7/03/2018 4:48:01 PM, ChangeTime: 7/03/2018 4:48:01 PM, FileAttributes: D, AllocationSize: 4,096, EndOfFile: 4,096, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: True, IndexNumber: 0x400000012fdb9, EaSize: 0, Access: Generic Read, Position: 0, Mode: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, AlignmentRequirement: Word
5:00:39.1652737 PM  SearchIndexer.exe   4652    CloseFile   C:\rubytest\proj    SUCCESS 
5:00:39.1696011 PM  ruby.exe    896 CloseFile   C:\rubytest\proj\testa  SUCCESS 
5:00:39.1780143 PM  ruby.exe    5800    CloseFile   C:\rubytest\proj\testa  SUCCESS
```

Comment: `Errno::EACCES: Permission denied` have you tried with a user with needed privileges, or by giving permission?

Comment: @SebastianPalma  I tried from an administrative cmd prompt, which is pretty much as privileged as can be or would need to be,  in windows.  It's not clear to me what it is trying to do that it thinks it is being denied. From a windows perspective I could even delete the file from a regular cmd prompt.

Comment: are you also using any db browser or other software at the same time for exploring database which takes a lock over your db ? @barlop

Comment: @AakashGupta no i'm not running any db browser or any software locking the file.. and as I said, the file isn't locked. I can delete the file if I want and have done   as mentioned in my q  and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this line does it, `rails db:drop:_unsafe`

see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31589

```
C:\rubytest\h\testaa1>rails db:drop:_unsafe
Dropped database 'db/development.sqlite3'
Dropped database 'db/test.sqlite3'

C:\rubytest\h\testaa1>
```

Comment: @worrawut My question shows `Rails 5.1.4` so not the latest but is rails 5. Are you tryiing tu soggest you had rails 4.x/4.x.x, had the problem, didn't upgrade for years, then upgraded to rails 5.x/5.x.x?

Comment: sorry that my message misunderstood. I mean I run Rails 5 (5.2.0) as well and your answers help me solve the same problem I have. Good day!

Comment: @worrawut clicking + to upvote is sufficient then.. Also your comment reminded me to accept the answer ('cos I wrote the question too!) it took me a year after asking the question, to find the solution! II have been using a mac running osx for a year because of it. The rails team care so little about windows users.